# Chamar uma procedure PL/SQL passando uma data como parâmetro

Tags: java, pl-sql

Eu tenho uma procedure PL/SQL

```
( LnCDOrigem            IN Company.COD_CD%TYPE,
   LnSotoreOrigem       IN Company.COD_STORE%TYPE,
   LvTipoEqpt           IN VARCHAR2,
   LdDtMovimento        IN DATE,
   LnRetorno            OUT NUMBER)
```

Quando faço a chamada dela pelo Java recebo um seguinte erro

```
ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected
ORA-06512: at line 1
```

Meu codigo java está assim

```
CallableStatement statement = getConnection().prepareCall(
            "{ Call PCK_ABERTURA_CONTABIL.Abrir_Data_Contabil(:LnCDOrigem, :LnSotoreOrigem, " +
                    ":tipoEquipamento, :dataMovimento, :retorno) }");
    Date dataMovimento = Date.valueOf(dataHora);
    statement.setLong("LnCDOrigem", codigoOrigem);
    statement.setLong("LnStoreOrigem", codigoStore);
    statement.setDate("dataMovimento", dataMovimento);
    statement.setString("tipoEquipamento", "M");
    statement.registerOutParameter("retorno", OracleTypes.NUMBER);
    statement.execute();
    return statement.getLong("retorno");
```

Comment: Assim não dá pra saber muito bem o que é, a unica informação que temos é que em um dos campos ele está esperando um numero e recebendo um "não numero", tenta habilitar o log pra mostrar o sql gerado, acredito que vá facilitar identificar o problema

Comment: Descobrir que mesmo passando os paramentros com chave e valor, só deu certo quando coloquei eles na ordem da chamada da PL/SQL.]